# Overriding "Change Password" Template from FOS User Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I did some research and sadly couldn't find any help for that.

So I'm rendering the FOSUserBundle ChangePasswordAction into a template of mine, but it displays the default template given from the vendor.

My template where the controller is rendered:

```
{% block body %}
    <h2>Einstellungen</h2>
    <br/>
    <h4>Ändern Sie ihr Passwort</h4>
    {% render controller("FOSUserBundle:ChangePassword:changePassword") %}
{% endblock %}
```

My template for the ChangePasswordAction, the path is `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/ChangePassword/changePassword.html.twig`:

```
{% block fos_user_content %}
    {% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

    <form action="{{ path('fos_user_change_password') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_change_password">
        {{ form_start(form) }}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
            <p><span class="edit_left_date">{{ form_label(form.current_password, 'Jetziges Passwort') }} </span>
                <span class="edit_right">{{ form_widget(form.current_password) }}</span></p>
            <p><span class="edit_left_date">{{ form_label(form.new_password, 'Neues Passwort') }} </span>
                <span class="edit_right">{{ form_widget(form.new_password) }}</span></p>
            <p><span class="edit_left_date">{{ form_label(form.new_password_confirmation 'Bestätigen Sie ihr neues Passwort') }} </span>
                <span class="edit_right">{{ form_widget(form.new_password_confirmation) }}</span></p>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="{{ 'Speichern'|trans }}" />
            </div>
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

What drives me crazy is that i render the login controller from the FOSUserBundle the same way in my layout.html.twig and it's working perfectly there.

The snippet of code from the layout:

```
{% block sidebar %}
    {% render controller("FOSUserBundle:Security:Login") %}
{% endblock %}
```

and the `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Security/login.html.twig`:

```
{% block fos_user_content %}
    <div class="teaser-header">Login</div>
        <form role="form" action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">{{ 'MyLog Username'|trans }}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="_username" placeholder="Your Username" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">{{ 'Password'|trans }}</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="Your Password" required="required" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'Segel setzen'|trans }}" />
            <a id="passwordForget" href={{ path('fos_user_resetting_request') }}>Password vergessen?</a>
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Am i missing something or what am i doing wrong so i can't override the `changePassword` Template?

Comment: Have you cleared your cache since adding the new template?

Comment: Yes, from browser and from the server, also tried different browser, nothing worked

Comment: The only one that would affect the templates would be the server but as you've done that I'm not sure. You seem to have the same setup as me and it does work.

Comment: I can't close this question, but i took my computer off from energy for quite some time to really clear all caches (im working on a local virtual server). Seems like the cache:clear didn't work correclty. Since you're right with your comment i would accept you answer if you post it as one :) I can't close this question because of the anwer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving from comments to an answer:

Have you cleared your cache since adding the new template?

Comment: From the Question Comments:  i took my computer off from energy for quite some time to really clear all caches (im working on a local virtual server). Seems like the cache:clear didn't work correclty.

Answer (score 2):

What you basically do is you create a user bundle of your own + set it's parent to the FOS user bundle. (You should already have done this step)

Then you set the template in:
`MyCompany/MyProject/UserBundle/Resources/views/Resetting/request.html.twig`

Because of the fact that the file in the FOS user bundle is on the same place, your file will overwrite that template.

Comment: Meaning that you need put your overwrite template in another directory. In my case it was src/AppBundle/UserBundle/Resources/views/ChangePassword/changePassword.html.twig

Comment: I did not set the FOSUserBundle as parent because according to the [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md) you can do this also by just override them to the `app/Resources/..` folder. It worked for the login Template, so why is it not working for the changePassword?

Comment: And what if you try to set it as it's parent?

Answer (score 0):

If you think you've done everything correctly and still it doesn't work, you can try to clear the cache with a Symfony command in the terminal, or in some cases manually delete the cache directories - 'app/cache/dev' or 'app/cache/prod'.