# Symfony - override FOSUserBundle changePassword_content

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I tried everything that is reported in the docs [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html) as well as [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/2098) and on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386601/overriding-change-password-template-from-fos-user-bundle).

Declaring `app\Resources\FOSUserBundle\views\ChangePassword\changePassword_content.html.twig` doesn't work. The replaced translations in `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/translations/FOSUserBundle.fr.yml` are fine, so the directory should be ok... But it simply won't replace the template.

I tried also to put it in my child bundle that override the `FOSUserBundle` in the views and it didn't work either (I guess for this to work I would have to override controllers as well as the FormType, and I don't need that currently I simply want to style the form).

Is there a configuration to do somewhere that I'm missing ?

Thanks ahead !

Comment: try renaming the file `change_password_content.html.twig`

Comment: It... Works ! Seriously ? Could you explain why the hell it works, since the base template has the name I gave, and it's also the name I found everywhere on the internet ?! Oh and add your comment as an answer so I can feed you some points by happily validating it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file in FosuserBundle is named `ChangePassword/change_password_content.html.twig` - it's useful to copy the original file and then edit it to help ensure it is exactly the same.

A version update in the 2.0beta moved files to 'under_score' casing (directory paths are still in MixedCase).

The link referring to `changePassword_content.html.twig` wasn't relevant, and was ultimately wrong.